# How could I define the route for RestAPI on startup in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I know how to define the route using attribute, eg:

```
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class OTGController
    {
        [HttpGet("UpdateData")]
        public void UpdateData()
        {
            // to do...
        }
    }
```

But this is not very easy to use, I need to config it any time when I add a new controller.

First, the route for the controller is always: "api/v1/[controller]". I don't want to configure it in each controller.

Second, the route for `UpdateData` is "UpdateData". They are the same. I want to define it like:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public void UpdateData()
        {
            // to do...
        }
```

If I leave the route with empty, I want it to use the method name `UpdateData` as the route. This is different from the default behavior.
If it is not empty, I want it to use the route defined.

I want my final code like:

```
    [ApiController]
    public class OTGController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public void UpdateData()
        {
            // to do...
        }
    }
```

No route is defined in this class and the route should be generated successfully according to the rule I configure on startup.
How?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

You can override the default `EndpointMiddleware` middleware. Update the function `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` on `Startup` class.

```
...
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "Default",
        "api/v1/{controller}/{action=UpdateData}"
    );
});
...
```

***Warning:*** You will need to remove the `ApiControllerAttribute` to your Api controller(s). Action methods on controllers annotated with `ApiControllerAttribute` must be attribute routed.

**Solution 2:**

You can always create an API base controller class.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class ApiControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("")]
    public virtual IActionResult UpdateData()
    {
        return NoContent();
    }
}

public class OTGController : ApiControllerBase
{
    public override IActionResult UpdateData()
    {
        return Ok("Updated!");
    }
}
```

**Solution 3:**

`EndpointMiddleware` configuration:

```
...
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        "Default",
        "api/v1/{controller}/{action=UpdateData}"
    );

    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
...
```

Controllers:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class ApiControllerBase : ControllerBase
{
}

public class OTGController : ApiControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult UpdateData()
    {
        return Ok("Updated!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very very much. The first one, I tried: I added the default MapControllerRoute and removed `[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]` from the controller .  The path for the api becomes: "/UpdateData". And after I removed the route paramter from `HttpGet` attribute. The web API is gone. This solution is not working for me. Trying the 2nd one

Comment: The 2nd: Yes it solved my first problem, the controller route is fixed to `    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]` by the base class.   But my 2nd problem remaining unsolved. I cannot add the methd to the base class.

Comment: @HalfLegend both solution are tested for me. It should work. Anyway, for solution 2, you can make a variation. You can remove the virtual function and override the default action in the `EndpointMiddleware` middleware. I will add a 3 solution to show this variant.